# Do Prompto's photos have a practical/mechanical purpose (in and of themselves)?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

The title sums it up.

I am aware there are several side quests that involve going to take pictures, but those quests reward experience and/or AP. (And there's an trophy/achievement for looking at a pic with a photo bomber in it) Will discarding all photos without review affect the my game in any practical way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**

The OP has already pointed out the few minor bonuses that taking pictures can provide the player. Shawn's answer does point out an end game action using the pictures, but that has no practical game play purpose.

Answer (score 4):

### **TL;DR:**

***Yes and No.***

It largely depends on your purpose for playing and how technical and meta you wish to view the intention.

If you're playing to say you played it and just want to push through in a rote sense, or hit a point where you aren't compelled to 'feel' about the game and it's characters:

***No*** there is not practical gameplay value to them.

If you look for immersion and prefer to allow the game to draw emotional response in a way the developer intends and hopes, then:

***Yes*** (arguably).

### **Explanation:**

Discard without review doesn't directly impact anything in terms of trophy / achievement but reviewing photos is *a necessary step* in how they're saved (review is triggered by selection of the photo, which is why you'll hear banter over some photos and trigger the acquisition of an trophy / achievement).

The option to save photos indirectly impacts other portions of the game, specifically the ending sequences in ways that can be major or minor depending on how you value things like storytelling and emotional investment (something the game pines for from the audience).

Prompto's photos *do* have mechanical purpose in a meta sense. The series of side-quests that require Prompto to take photos and yields very high Gil reward, which is technically a mechanic of the game using the photos and the player is forced to review (but not save) them upon completion of each portion of the side-quest.

Additionally, certain locations and landmarks give the option to take photos, some Prompto will notify the player about, which builds a sense of how the characters interact with one another without really impacting their response in a sense of the mechanics you are most likely thinking about. Prompto will also occasionally ask Noctis who he prefers pictures of, and that directly impacts a *meta* mechanic, and arguably practical in nature.

***A direct mechanic impact as well as practical impact of photos is revealed prior to the final boss fight.***

Noct will have an opportunity to choose his favorite photo as a keepsake before heading in to fulfill his destiny. This, and all other saved photos will adorn the ending credits as a slideshow of what the player accomplished *with the keepsake photo becoming the certificate of completion image for FFXV*.

Thus, why not reviewing and deleting photos for the first play-through can lessen the experience of the game for some players.

### NG+ Depth:

When / If you start NG+, all saved photos and the certificate of completion will remain in the Archives menu under Photos. Deleting photos altogether or deleting and replacing them upon the next round of completion will just alter what photos are used in the ending credits.

NG+ has a purpose many seem to immediately overlook and it's in the power boost gives the game a pace in-line with theatrical flow and presentation more than when you start out to have the FFXV RPG experience. This is especially true with the movie *King's Glaive* as a preamble to the game.

Given the ending credits entail the saved photos, reviewing them allows you to choose how you remember the journey. It's left to *you* to give it practicality from the established layered mechanic, more so if you felt underwhelmed in the first play-through with knowledge of what's coming.

Comment: I feel we must have different definitions of practical and/or mechanical, b/c according to the body of your post, photography has only cosmetic effects. Changing the final cutscene, imo, isn't a mechanical effect. If saving pictures of a certain monster gave you a damage boost against them, that would be mechanical.

Comment: I also take issue with your assumption that not caring about photos in a game automatically means you can't make an emotional connection with the characters. The game is better written than that.

Comment: "Game mechanics are constructs of rules or methods designed for interaction with the game state." 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_mechanics

I operated on something rather strict in definition. 

You must review the photo to save it (a rule of the game state). Regardless of what the rule effects, be it a cosmetic or something that enhances an ability directly. Note that mode of play is itself a mechanic of play.

Comment: "If you're just playing to say you played it... or hit a point where you aren't compelled to "feel" about the game... No... If you... prefer to allow the game to draw an emotional response... Yes." I can't see how you meant anything other than something like "Photography is vital to establishing an emotional connection, and you can ignore it only at the expense of that emotional connection." If that wasn't your intention, the beginning of answer needs an edit.

Comment: If you want to debate your opinion, great but that's all it is and there's a place for that. I'm fairly certain this isn't the proper forum though.

Answer (score -1):

Pictures give you nothing by themselves. You can do the picture missions and then choose not to save them and you won't lose anything. They are just meant to be cute and fun.

Answer (score -2):

No. Deleting those Photos without viewing them will not discard the items, XP, or AP you earned from doing those side quests.

Comment: Part of the question answers itself (trophy for reviewing a photo with a specific feature). He didn't ask if saving them had impact (though they do, indirectly and superficially if you choose to feel that way).